# fatal error in grammar - piecewise definition

Tags: antlr, antlr3, context-free-grammar

I am translating a grammar from LALR to ANTLR and I am having trouble with translating this one rule, piecewise expression.

Attached is the sample grammar:

```
grammar Test;
options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
}

parse : expression ';'
      ;

expression : binaryExpression
           | piecesExpression
           ;

binaryExpression : addingExpression (('=='|'!='|'<='|'>='|'>'|'<') addingExpression)*
                 ;

addingExpression : multiplyingExpression (('+'|'-') multiplyingExpression)*
                 ;

multiplyingExpression : unaryExpression 
                        (('*'|'/') unaryExpression)*
                      ;

unaryExpression: ('!'|'-')* primitiveElement;   

primitiveElement : literalExpression
                 | id
                 | '(' expression ')'
                 ;  

literalExpression : INT
                  ;              

id : IDENTIFIER
   ;

piecesExpression : 'piecewise' '{' piece expression '}'  ('(' expression ',' expression ')')? expression?
                 ;

piece : expression '->' expression ';' (expression '->' expression ';')*
      ;


// L E X I C A L   R U L E S      

INT : DIGITS ;   

IDENTIFIER : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ;
fragment DIGITS: DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

ANTLR v3.5 is complaining about the piecesExpression rule. It has 2 fatal errors and I would rather not use backtrack option.

Expected results:

```
piecewise {t -> s; t -> x; 100}
piecewise {t -> s; t -> x; 100} (0, x+1) 
piecewise {t -> s; t -> x; 100} (0, x+1) y+5
```

How can piecesExpression be able to capture the above results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR has problems determining which alternatives to take in (at least) 2 cases:

1. `piece` starts with a `expression` but inside the `piecewise{...}`, it should also end with an `expression`
2. `piecesExpression` ends with `'(' expression ...` but also has an optional trailing `expression` (and an `primitiveElement` also matches `'(' expression ...` in its turn)

There's no need to use global backtracking, but without rewriting many rules, you do need to add some predicates (the `(...)=>` in the example below) to fix the two issues outlined above.

Try this:

```
piecesExpression
 : 'piecewise' '{' ((expression '->')=> piece)+ expression '}' 
     ( ('(' expression ',')=> '(' expression ',' expression ')' expression?
     |                        expression
     )
 ;

piece
 : expression '->' expression ';'
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, there is no way to do it without predicates?

Comment: @AndyM, no, AFAIK it is not possible without predicates.

Comment: Thanks again! You have been a tremendous help and is much appreciated!